# connect to odbc sage 100 using PHP

Tags: php, odbc, sage-erp

I want to connect To SAGE commerciale 100 using odbc sage with php : 
I've succeeded to connect only with MS Excel.
But with php I didn't

this my php code :

```
try
{
   $conn = odbc_connect("Driver=SAGE Gestion commerciale 
   100;Server=localhost;Database=GestCom_Sage100;","username","password");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I got this error :

```
 SQL error: [Microsoft][Gestionnaire de pilotes ODBC] Source de données 
 introuvable et nom de pilote non spécifié, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect.
```

if I use new pdo instead of odbc_connect  i got the same error

```
 $conn = new PDO("odbc:GestCom_Sage100","username","password");
```

The error could be caused because am in windows 10 64 bits and I am using 32-bits odbc sage ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed My code to :

```
$dsn = "GestCom_Sage100";
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn,"username","password");
```

And I execute my code on windows 7 32 bits and it worked.
The problem was that ODBC sage is a 32 bits application used on 64 bits OS.